# Model mapper sharing or creating new modelMapper per mapper instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, modelmapper

I am creating an application using spring boot as framework and using model mapper for mapping objects between diffrent app is layers.
In my application i have many mappers to which i am actually usnig the same modelMapper which is instantiate as @config bean but the problem with this is sometimes the configs between mappers is entring in conlict.

Example for mapper1 i want to add a converter for dates which i don't want to use for mapper2.
So what shall i do?  i am thinking about a mapper like that (code bellow ) but the problem with that is memory as i will instantiate a new ModelMapper for each mapper

```
@Slf4j
@Setter
@Component
public class CarMapper{

  private ModelMapper mapper;


  @PostConstruct
  public void configure(){
     mapper = new ModelMapper();
    configureMapperToIgnoreNullValues();
    mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    mapper.getConfiguration().setFieldAccessLevel(Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
    addFromStringToDateConverterToMapper();
    addFromDateToStringConverterToMapper();
    addPropertyMapForCarDto();
    log.debug("Mapper configured");
  }

protected toCarDto(Car car){
// mapping code here
}

 public void addPropertyMapForCarDto() {
    // check if a type map exist for Car, CarDto
    if (mapper.getTypeMap(Car.class, CarDto.class) == null) {

      TypeMap<Car, CarDto> propertyMapper = mapper.createTypeMap(
          Car.class, CarDto.class);
      propertyMapper.addMappings(
          addedMapper -> addedMapper.map(Car::getId,
             CarDto::setId));
      log.debug("Property mapping for CarDto added to mapper");
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ModelMapper objects can be defined as Spring beans - mark one of them with @Primary annotation and inject second one by its qualifier where needed.

This would help to use 1 mapper as-is - and second can also be used in other classes with use of @Qualifier

Answer (score 0):

Yes modelMapper instance can be shared, but if you have differents typeMap mapping the same class to another the same class you need to create new modelMapper or remove the old typeMap and set the new typeMap.

I usually share the same modelMapper instance, but in the mapper i use the  method annotated with @PostConstruct to build the typeMap with all the property mappings one time in the lifecycle of this mapper.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ObjectMapper{

   private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

   @PostConstruct 
   public void postConstructor() {
      // here put your typeMap and propertyMappings

      this.modelMapper.createTypeMap(ObjectDTORequest.class, ObjectEntity.class)
        .implicitMappings()
        .addMappings(mapping -> mapping.map(dto::getProperty, entity::setProperty));
   }

   public Objectentity mapTo(ObjectDtoRequest objDtoRequest){
      //your mp logic.
   }
}
```

So I can use the same Mapper to map a lot of requests without worry about errors.